# Add caption below table using kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I am building a table using kable and I would like to add a caption below the tale. However, the caption is automatically set above the table.
Is there a way to change this?

Thanks a lot!

```
tb <- kable(x, caption = 'yyy', digits=c(0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2), booktabs=T) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options="scale_down")
```

Comment: I think `knitr` keeps it intentionally simple and only considers the standard that everyone uses: tables have the caption above, figures below. if you want more andvanced controll i'd suggest checking out kableExtra, xtable or any of the many packages for markup (i.e. latex, markdown) ([similar question](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/221#issuecomment-400473530))

Answer (score 1):

How about using `footnote` ?

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

kable(mtcars[1:5, 1:5], booktabs=T) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options="scale_down") %>%
  footnote(general = "yyy", general_title = "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For HTML output, you may add this CSS snippet to your RMarkdown document:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
table { caption-side: bottom }
```
````